# excel powerpivot data modeling with 2 non-unique key relation

Tags: excel, data-modeling, powerpivot

So I have two tables, Products and Orders.

The Products table contains the following columns: ID, Name, Type.

The Orders table contains the following columns: ID, Name, Quantity.

In both tables, neither ID or Name is unique, but together they are. Is it possible for Excel PowerPivot to make a relationship between the two tables using these two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create relationship using multiple columns in Powerpivot. You have to create a single column using multiple columns, which make up the key.

[Reference](https://www.kasperonbi.com/troubleshooting-powerpivot-relationships/)

> When you have multiple columns that make a key you should create a new
> column, use CONCATENATE or & to create a composite column, and that
> will serve as your key.